# absolute positioning of image?

Tags: html, pdf

does this mean the image will be locked in place no matter what's around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In context of HTML, absolutely positioning anything means it's essentially "taken out of the flow" - it does not affect the placement of other elements, and other elements don't affect the placement of it